# Why is the catkin_make command showing error?

Tags: catkin-make

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Output:

```
riddhi@riddhi-Inspiron-N5010:~/catkin_ws$ catkin_make
Base path: /home/riddhi/catkin_ws
Source space: /home/riddhi/catkin_ws/src
Build space: /home/riddhi/catkin_ws/build
Devel space: /home/riddhi/catkin_ws/devel
Install space: /home/riddhi/catkin_ws/install
####
#### Running command: "make cmake_check_build_system" in "/home/riddhi/catkin_ws/build"
####
####
#### Running command: "make -j4 -l4" in "/home/riddhi/catkin_ws/build"
####
../catkin_generated/env_cached.sh: 16: exec: /usr/local/bin/python: not found
beginner_tutorials/CMakeFiles/_beginner_tutorials_generate_messages_check_deps_AddTwoInts.dir/build.make:57: recipe for target 'beginner_tutorials/CMakeFiles/_beginner_tutorials_generate_messages_check_deps_AddTwoInts' failed
make[2]: *** [beginner_tutorials/CMakeFiles/_beginner_tutorials_generate_messages_check_deps_AddTwoInts] Error 127
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:784: recipe for target 'beginner_tutorials/CMakeFiles/_beginner_tutorials_generate_messages_check_deps_AddTwoInts.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [beginner_tutorials/CMakeFiles/_beginner_tutorials_generate_messages_check_deps_AddTwoInts.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
../catkin_generated/env_cached.sh: 16: exec: /usr/local/bin/python: not found
beginner_tutorials/CMakeFiles/_beginner_tutorials_generate_messages_check_deps_Num.dir/build.make:57: recipe for target 'beginner_tutorials/CMakeFiles/_beginner_tutorials_generate_messages_check_deps_Num' failed
make[2]: *** [beginner_tutorials/CMakeFiles/_beginner_tutorials_generate_messages_check_deps_Num] Error 127
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:656: recipe for target 'beginner_tutorials/CMakeFiles/_beginner_tutorials_generate_messages_check_deps_Num.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [beginner_tutorials/CMakeFiles/_beginner_tutorials_generate_messages_check_deps_Num.dir/all] Error 2
[  0%] Built target std_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
[  0%] Built target std_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
Makefile:138: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
Invoking "make -j4 -l4" failed
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/278751/why-is-the-catkin_make-command-showing-error?/) by [rid7](https://answers.ros.org/users/30774/rid7/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2018-01-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Seems like python is not found where it is expected:

```
/usr/local/bin/python: not found
```

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2018-01-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1